# Loop through variables with prop.table in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a simple problem. I am trying to loop through a set of variables to generate prop.tables. I am merely trying to inspect the results visually.

Here is a meaningless example from the mtcars dataset.

```
#define loop variables
test <- mtcars
target_var <- c("mpg", "wt")   # targets
group_var <- c("gear", "carb")   # groups to loop through

#loop through combinations of targets and groups, running prop.table
for (i in target_var) {
  for (j in group_var) {

    print(prop.table(table(test$i, test$j), 2))
  }
}
```

The output is 6 of the following:

```
<0 x 0 matrix>
```

I know I'm missing something basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test$i` won't work. There is no column `i` in the `mtcars` data frame - operator `$` won't resolve a variable name. You probably meant `test[i, ]` or `test[, i]`.

Please also note that there is no column nor row named `"3"` and `"4"`, so iteration over `group_var` would not give anything meaningful.

Comment: Then use `test[, i]` and `test[, j]`.

Comment: like this: `print(prop.table(table(test[, i], test[, j]), 2))`

Answer (score 2):

I see you're interested in a loop solution, but I'll post a `tidyverse` approach where you can `map` your function to each combination of your variables, instead of having a loop.

```
test <- mtcars
target_var <- c("mpg", "wt")
group_var <- c("gear", "carb")

library(tidyverse)

# get combinations of variables in a dataset
df1 = expand.grid(target_var, group_var, stringsAsFactors = F)

# apply the function (prop.table etc.) to those combinations
map2(df1$Var1, df1$Var2, ~prop.table(table(test[, .x], test[, .y]), 2))
```

This will give you a list with the tables you want as elements.

Comment: AntoniosK, this is sweet! I hadn't seen this approach before. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As Maciej mentions, you can't just count on that `test$i` gets evaluated so that `i` is replaced with the column you want to extract. We can however use functions `parse_expr` and `eval` to control what gets evaluated, and when. Minor changes to your code makes this work:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

#define loop variables
test <- mtcars
target_var <- c("mpg", "wt")   # targets
group_var <- c("gear", "carb")   # groups to loop through

#loop through combinations of targets and groups, running prop.table
for (i in target_var) {
  for (j in group_var) {
    a <- paste0("test$", i) %>% parse_expr()
    b <- paste0("test$", j) %>% parse_expr()
    print(prop.table(table(eval(a), eval(b)), 2))
  }
}
```